# SalesforceBaseException: Missing Fields or Field Mismatch between the Data Extension and the Report

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Our org has various clients that use the automation studio for SF Report imports & we use these Salesforce Data Extensions as Entry Sources in our Journeys.

For a few weeks now we have noticed that across various brands these imports fail every 10 minutes but randomly. In this specific example we are using automation on an hourly schedule and an import activity will fail at 8am, complete at 9am, fail at 10, then complete absolutely fine until 6am next morning.

The next day the pattern of failure can be different but an average I have 10% failed instances, 90% successfully completed instances.

I raised a case with support but didn't get much help. All I was able to determine is that our import version is 6 and the error message they could see is the following:

> Import Exception: Could not query report id: 00O0O00000AXXXXXx --->
>   SalesforceBaseException: Could not query report id: 00O0O00000AXXXXXx
>   --->  SalesforceBaseException: Missing Fields or Field Mismatch between the Data Extension and the Report.  Could not find some or all
>   of the fields: Request_Type, Request: Data Source, Selling Company:
>   Account Name, Lead_Created_Date, Contact ID,  First_Name, Last_Name,
>   Email, Customer or Prospect: Account Record Type, Created Date, Record
>   Type, Marketing Consent IN  at SalesforceReport.AddFields(String[]
>   csvFields) at SalesforceReport.AddRow(String[] row) at
>   SalesforceReport.PopulateReport()

I do not understand why this error would appear; I have checked the report type that we are using and this was last modified over 2 months ago (whereas I keep getting these failed instances daily) & Also I checked the fields on the objects and these were last modified 2-3 years ago ( we tend not to touch too much the Salesforce structure for the fields considering so many brands use these reports).

Any insight is much appreciated!

Giulietta

Comment: Not sure if its relevant or not: We have an Enterprise 2.0 marketing cloud account and one salesforce org. We have multiple business units integrated with various tracking users. We do not use scope by user in any of the business units integrated. We are at the latest level with the connector.

Also I see these errors regardless if the imports are setup to Add and Update or Overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Report Imports tend to fail if during the import time someone is running these reports in Salesforce. In essence, even merely opening the report *may* cause the import to fail.

Often if the source Data Extension (to which you have imported Data over the span of years) gets too big it can cause timeout issues.

Anyway, try the following > in Salesforce create a new folder in Reports section, create a copy of all the reports to that folder and limit access to only admins and integration user and do not run these reports ever for manual reasons or parts of dashboard components.

Use these reports in that folder for a few MC import activities. If it helps then do the same for the rest of the reports.